# How to remove black pixels in Landsat image

Tags: erdas-imagine, landsat, landsat-8

[image]Does anyone know how I can remove these black pixels around the edge of this Landsat image? They appeared when I layer-stacked the bands in ERDAS IMAGINE - they were not there in the separate band images.

Comment: Can you show us the image you are working with, and the specific source you got it from?

Comment: I've just added the layer-stacked image. I downloaded the imagery from USGS Earth Explorer

Comment: Have you checked which value it is (inquire tool)? Maybe you could make it transparent then. Or you try to clip the result with an intersection of the inputs!?

Comment: Thanks for advice, I did the layer stack again and ticked 'intersection' and it worked!